# Is there a free source for flat/32-bit character avatars to build off of?

Tags: assets

I'd like to use some pixel characters as a base for tweaking into characters for my browser-based-game http://ninjawars.net .  (In other words, I take a base template and I modify it with colors and pixels slightly to make character variations)

Now, my bbg is mostly ninja oriented, so a ninja avatar to work off of would be great, but more varied character types would be good as well.  And I can probably fudge a "ninja" from some other template.

But, err, free-to-use-for-commercial-purposes (e.g. public domain) would be necessary.  I'm already makin' a little money off the site from Ads, and would certainly like to make more, so I can't use stuff for "non-commercial use only", unfortunately.

So any source for free-for-commercial-use pixel-y 32-bit-y characters to use as a starting design base?

Comment: Related: http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/20/where-can-i-find-free-sprites-and-images

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a couple of nice resources.

Try Reiner's tilesets:
http://www.reinerstilesets.de/

This is a terrific set of sprites. All were created originally with a 3D modeler, and then cut into 2D images. Many images have multiple animations from multiple viewpoints.  Most of the images are in a traditional RPG theme, but there's a good chance you can find something you like. They are free to use in your own games with permission.

I also like Ari's spritelib:
http://www.flyingyogi.com/fun/spritelib.html
This guy wrote a book about creating 2D game graphics, and he's done graphics for several games. He released a terrific set of graphics under the GPL license. These graphics are a bit more dated, but they are also a super starting place.

There's another great set available here:
http://www.lostgarden.com/2007/05/dancs-miraculously-flexible-game.html

I haven't used these tiles myself, but they look beautiful. They're a bit 'cuter' than you're probably looking for.

Yet another nice royalty-free set available here:
http://www.spicypixel.net/2008/01/10/gfxlib-fuzed-a-free-developer-graphic-library/
This set looks ideal for platformers. I may use it in one of my upcoming books. (I've already used ari and reiner works)

Hope this helps...

Comment: links are mostly all invalid now, need to be updated.